# Spiking neural network on FPGA

Tags: neural-network, verilog

I am trying to implement LIF neuron (with two delay constants alpha and beta,one for membrane potential and other for synaptic current),in verilog. Now how can I model a tau_m = 100ms in verilog (digital - so I have to subtract a value ). Is there any reference

I tried with existing codes but which leak value to be subtracted I am not sure

Comment: Please post the code you have tired, and describe how is not meeting your needs.